# File not found on http://localhost:8080/

Tags: java

I have just installed Tomcat7 using `apt-get install tomcat7`. In CATALINA_HOME I can see default index.html file and it runs fine using `localhost:8080/`. Now I have placed a .war file to deploy in this same folder and run `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge.war` and `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge` as well, but it won't work. It says `HTTP Status 404 - /JavaBridge`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deploying the war by using tomcat manager. Set the tomcat user in `conf/tomcat-users.xml`, type `http://localhost:8080/manager` on your browser, and then deploy it using Tomcat-GUI manager. Make sure you give manager-gui and manager roles to your user.

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the war file in the correct Tomcat directory and then by default the name of the WAR file defines the context root.  Then your web.xml file (unless you are using anotations) defines these rest of the URL by way of servlet mappings.  Thus the full URL you type in the browser is: 
`http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/<servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Thanks. Where is web.xml?